# Is there a way to tell if an activerecord query hit its limit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

given the following query:

```
Cars.where(color: red).limit(5)
```

Is there a way to tell if the limit was hit.  Say there are 6 red cars, do I have to do a separate query to count the total number of red cars?

Basically, I am trying to send a message to the user letting them know that a search was limited due to reaching max number of results allowed.

Comment: If you are displaying the last 5, the limit is not technically hit until the next page - at which point you'll know because you have received < 5 results back.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way to combine it into one query is to do a limit(6).  If the size is 6, then remove the last element and record that their are more results.

Alternatively, do a separate query Cars.where(color: red).count.  Although this will do a separate SQL query, count queries are sometimes very fast for databases.

Comment: Wow, that's a nice Gotcha (your first proposition)! I'll keep that in mind for later

Comment: Yeah, I like the first idea.

Answer (score 0):

The direct answer to your question is that you cannot get this information back in one single query.  You would have to run two queries: one to return the limited set, and one to find the total count.

The only time this wouldn't be necessary is when you are querying the first page of results (the offset is 0) and the number of returned results is less than the limited value (e.g., you set the limit to 5 but get 4 results back).

Sample code would look like this:

```
    limit = 5
    cars_scoped = Cars.where(color: red)
    cars = cars_scoped.limit(limit)
    cars_count = cars.length < limit ? cars.length : cars_scoped.count
```

Comment: Avoid a second query for count if the results are few enough that you already know.  Nice.